# How to do gradle build on nested projects

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am trying to build the java projects with gradle and my project structure something like below:

```
Root
|
|----Child
|      |
|      Child1 (build.gradle)
|      
|
|----Child12
|     |
|     Child111
|     |
|    Child222(build.gradle)
|
settings.gradle
```

As you can see, the project structure, here I am doing the `gradle eclipse build` for all the projects (Child1, Child222) in a single attempt by modifying `settings.gradle` and including the child projects something like below:

```
include 'Child/Child1'
include 'Child12/Child111/Child222'
```

Build is fine with that.
Whereas, while importing the projects(Child1, Child222) into eclipse, I am getting the following error:
Creation Problems

```
Path for project must have only one segment.
```

Because, in the Child1 `.project` file

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>Root/Child1</name>
<projectDescription>
```

project name appearing as `Root/Child1`, instead of `Child1`.
Is there anyway, with that I can import the projects into the eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I changed `settings.gradle` file like below:

```
include 'Child:Child1'
include 'Child12:Child111:Child222'
```

It's working fine for me.